# Angular 1/Jasmine - Test element if exist inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test the existence of an input that is inside an ng-if, without the ng-if the test passes perfectly but not with the ng-if which is normal since ng-if removes the element from the DOM.

In my template i have :

```
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShowAir">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>
```

In my component

```
  shouldShow() {
    this.shouldShowAir = (this.parkingType.labelKey === 'parking_type.air')
  }
```

Unit test

```
import angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

let scope
let rootScope
let compile
let htmlElement
let ctrl

fdescribe('projectExteriorParking', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('ProjectExteriorParkingModule')
    angular.mock.module('ui.select')
  })

  beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_
    compile = _$compile_
    scope = rootScope.$new()
    scope.parking = {}
    htmlElement = compile(`<project-exterior-parking parking="project.realEstateProjectProduct.parkings"></project-exterior-parking>`)(scope)
    rootScope.$digest()
  }))

  beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
    let bindings = {
      parking: {},
      projectReferences: {}
    }
    ctrl = $componentController('projectExteriorParkingModule', null, bindings)
  }))

  it('should contain two input', () => {
    const inputItems = htmlElement.get(0).querySelectorAll('input')
    expect(inputItems.length).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

How i can simulate that the variable `shouldShowAir` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

You should write two tests and mock

```
this.parkingType.labelKey
```

to false in the first test and test for the input to be null.
Then mock it to false and test for the input to be defined.

Or you only write one test, mock labelKey to true and run your existing test 'should contain two input'